# How to make Visual Studio build to fail on ReSharper Error

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, resharper

How can I make my code build to fail when ReSharper detects an "Error" after code inspection?

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2017 along with ReSharper. I have set the inspection severity of **Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'** to show as "Error". This setting only shows a red underline for erroneous code, however the VS build still succeeds if I just ignore it. I want to make the build to fail if developer ignores such errors detected by ReSharper inspection.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**I'm afraid Resharper seems to not support this option for now.**

1.In my opinion, the `error` level in `C#\Potential Code Quality Issues` is something like showing a red underline to indicate where there maybe has a risk to help improve your code. And red to indicate this issue deserves attention. Actually,it's something controlled by us, we determine to make them error(red line) or warning(blue line?).

But such a potential code issue can't be recognized by msbuild (build system in vs). So the build will ignore these potential issues and succeeds.

2.For build settings in Resharper, I tried msbuild settings and compiler settings like below:

[image]

[image]

I set every element in the Potential Code Quality Issues to `error`. Also, i set null reference related settings like below:

[image]

After that I create a simple `null reference` but the build ignores that and succeeds. Same result when I use Resharper build.(Resharper options=>Tools=>Build=>Build engine) So maybe it's a negative answer :(

Comment: Thanks @Lance.. Unfortunately, I need to stick with that for now.. But thanks for a nice explanation and your efforts digging that out further

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :) Any update please feel free to share here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal solution, but JetBrains provide a command line tool called [InspectCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/InspectCode.html) which runs their code inspections on your solution and outputs the results in XML or other formats. You could add a custom MSBuild step which runs `InspectCode.exe MySolution.sln -o=output.xml`, examines output.xml for errors, and fails the build if any are found.

Unfortunately InspectCode is slow and even though the analyses seem to be cached across runs it still takes a significant amount of time. For example, on my solution of 700k lines of code the tool takes 60 seconds on the second run, i.e. with a warm cache. So I don't think this is a viable solution to run on developer machines on every build. It might be acceptable in an automated build system.